# Systemd kills service immediately after start

Tags: centos, systemd, kill

I'm writing `systemd` unit files for OSSEC HIDS. The problem is that when `systemd` starts the services it immediately stops them.

When I use the following `ExecStart` directive everything is working fine.

```
ExecStart=/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control start
```

But when I make ths following small improvement, I find in OSSEC logs that it receives `SIG 15` after start.

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${DIRECTORY}/bin/ossec-control start'
```

If I make another small change, the service will receive `SIG 15` after 20 seconds.

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${DIRECTORY}/bin/ossec-control start && sleep 20'
```

So, I guess, that `systemd` kills `/bin/sh` process after service start, and `/bin/sh` then kills `OSSEC`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the Type of the service?

Comment: @Wieland, I was try simple and forking, but result is still the same.

Answer (score 45):

## readiness protocol mismatch

As Wieland implied, the `Type` of the service is important.  That setting denotes what *readiness protocol* systemd expects the service to speak.  A `simple` service is assumed to be immediately ready.  A `forking` service is taken to be ready after its initial process forks a child and then exits.  A `dbus` service is taken to be ready when a server appears on the Desktop Bus.  And so forth.

If you don't get the readiness protocol declared in the service unit to match what the service does, then things go awry.   Readiness protocol mismatches cause services not to start correctly, or (more usually) to be (mis-)diagnosed by systemd as failing.  When a service is seen as failing to start systemd ensures that *every orphaned additional process of the service* that might have been left running as part of the failure (from its point of view) is killed in order to bring the service properly back to the inactive state.

You're doing exactly this.

First of all, the simple stuff: `sh -c` doesn't match `Type=simple` or `Type=forking`.

In the `simple` protocol, the initial process is taken to *be* the service process.  But in fact a `sh -c` wrapper runs the actual service program *as a child process*.  So `MAINPID` goes wrong and `ExecReload` stops working, for starters.  When using `Type=simple`, one must either use `sh -c 'exec …'` or *not use* `sh -c` in the first place.  The latter is more often the correct course than some people think.

`sh -c` doesn't match `Type=forking` either.  The readiness protocol for a `forking` service is quite specific.  The initial process has to fork a child, and then exit.  systemd applies a timeout to this protocol.  If the initial process doesn't fork within the allotted time, it's a failure to become ready.  If the initial process doesn't exit within the allotted time, that too is a failure.

## the unnecessary horror that is `ossec-control`

Which brings us to the complex stuff: that `ossec-control` script.

[It turns out](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/tree/master/src/init) that it's a System 5 `rc` script that forks off between 4 and 10 processes, which themselves in their turn fork and exit too.  It's one of those System 5 `rc` scripts that attempts to manage a whole set of server processes in one single script, with `for` loops, race conditions, arbitrary `sleep`s to try to avoid them, failure modes that can choke the system in a half-started state, and all of the other horrors that got people inventing things like the AIX System Resource Controller and daemontools two decades ago.  And let's not forget the hidden shell script in a binary directory that it rewrites on the fly, to implement idiosyncratic `enable` and `disable` verbs.

So when you `/bin/sh -c '/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control start'` what happens is that:

1. systemd forks what it expects to be the service process.
2. That's the shell, which forks `ossec-control`.
3. That in turn forks between 4 and 10 grandchildren.
4. The grandchildren all fork and exit in turn.
5. The great-grandchildren all fork and exit in parallel.
6. `ossec-control` exits.
7. The first shell exits.
8. The service processes were the *great-great-*grandchildren, but because this way of working matches *neither* the `forking` *nor* the `simple` readiness protocol, systemd considers the service as a whole to have failed and shuts it back down.

None of this horror is actually necessary under systemd at all.  None of it.

## a systemd template service unit

Instead, one writes a very simple *template unit*:

```
[Unit]
Description=The OSSEC HIDS %i server
After=network.target 

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/env /var/ossec/bin/%p-%i -t
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env /var/ossec/bin/%p-%i -f

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save this this as `/etc/systemd/system/ossec@.service`.

The various actual services are *instantiations* of this template, named:

- `ossec@dbd.service`
- `ossec@agentlessd.service`
- `ossec@csyslogd.service`
- `ossec@execd.service`
- `ossec@agentd.service`
- `ossec@logcollector.service`
- `ossec@syscheckd.service`
- `ossec@maild.service`
- `ossec@analysisd.service`
- `ossec@remoted.service`
- `ossec@monitord.service`

Then enable and disable function *comes straight from the service management system* (with [RedHat bug 752774](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=752774) fixed), with no need for hidden shell scripts.

```
 systemctl enable ossec@dbd ossec@agentlessd ossec@csyslogd ossec@maild ossec@execd ossec@analysisd ossec@logcollector ossec@remoted ossec@syscheckd ossec@monitord
```

Moreover, systemd gets to know about, and to track, each actual service directly.  It can filter their logs with `journalctl -u`.  It can know when an individual service has failed.  It knows what services are supposed to be enabled and running.

By the way: `Type=simple` and the `-f` option are as right here as they are in many other cases.  Very few services in the wild *actually signal their readiness* by dint of the `exit`, and these here are not such cases either.  But that's what the `forking` type means.  Services in the wild in the main just fork and exit because of some mistaken received wisdom notion that that's what dæmons are supposed to do.  In fact, it's not.  It hasn't been since the 1990s.  It's time to catch up.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html). Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Very detailed answer! I'd also suggest to create a "grouping" target, say, ossec.target, which `Requires=` all the needed instances, and then set `PartOf=ossec.target` in ossec@.service. This will allow to start and stop ossec by starting and stopping ossec.target.

Comment: @JdeBP, wow! Thank a lot for such kind of detailed answer. Hope I'll make this unit and write here about results. I was though, that I'll be easier. But you are right, ossec-controll is a init hell.

Comment: What's the reason for using /usr/bin/env as a wrapper?

Comment: Got this issue after installing a fresh newer version of Ubuntu. A service with a config that worked normally would be deactivaded. After inserting `Type=forking` it started working normally.

Comment: *If the initial process doesn't fork within the allotted time, it's a failure to become ready. If the initial process doesn't exit within the allotted time, that too is a failure.* – what are these timeouts' lengths?

Comment: I'm wondering if using service template for different services doesn't go against intended use of service template mechanism which is for multiple instances of the same service…

Comment: Is using æ ligature in "dæmon" word correct? According to Wikipedia *Given their long history, ligatures are sometimes used to show archaism or in literal quotations of historic sources; for instance, in those contexts, words such as dæmon and æther are often so spelled.* Linux deamons are not archaic I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Keep `Type=forking` and give a PID file location if start service/app is maintaining any pid.

```
[Unit]
Description="Run app on boot"
After=network.target syslog.target auditd.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
Restart=on-failure
SyslogIdentifier=webappslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=webapps
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat related, I had a systemd service that it appeared that systemd would "kill" it after 30s.

`systemctl status service-name` would show `main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE` after 30s had elapsed.

It would run fine "in isolation" (like manually in the terminal with the [same environment](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1193453)).

Turns out it was

```
Type=forking
...
Environment=ABC="TRUE"
ExecStart=/path/to/my_script_to_spawn_process.sh
```

within `my_script_to_spawn_process.sh` it was doing

`/bin/something > /dev/null 2>&1 &`

which works but was discarding output log information (normally it goes to 
 a file, or, if not that, possibly `journalctl`).

Changing it to log to somewhere else like `/bin/something > /tmp/my_file`

then tailing the `/tmp/my_file` revealed the actual cause.  Which was (tangentially) that you can't use the syntax `Environment=ABC="true"` like you can in bash, it has to be no quotes or the key value all within quotes like `Environment="ABC=true"` which was causing my process to exit "in its setup phase" after about 30s.

Answer (score -4):

Note that systemd's daemon model is simplistic and incompatible with many existing daemons which do multiple forking, exec'ing and setuid'ing. Most common are the daemons which start as root to set things up and then switch to a less privileged UID for routine operation. e.g. Pid file initialization is one thing which fails under systemd due to privilege problems. There are workarounds (not fixes) but it's badly documented.

JdeBP's explanation is welcome but incomplete and his claim that it's all ossec-control's fault is simply not true. Even quite trivial stuff is problematic e.g. getting untruncated log lines to debug problems or meaningful error messages from systemd itself when it kills processes.

Comment: What use are PID files, anyway? If one exists for a given service, there may or may not be an actual process with that PID, and when a process with the right PID does exist, it may or may not actually be the expected service.