# CentOS 7 - why the service file is not working to run my bash script?

Tags: bash, centos, node.js

How to make my bash script as service in CentOS 7? following is failing.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/mybash.service
[Unit]
Description=mybash Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/root/runme.sh
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

$ systemctl start mybash
$ systemctl status mybash -l
mybash.service - mybash Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mybash.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
.....

$ cat /root/runme.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start the node server"
a=$(pgrep -f "a.js");
kill $a;
a=$(pgrep -f "b.js");
kill $a;
node /home/www/html/a.js &
node /home/www/html/b.js &
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Do it properly.

- Don't use `forever` under service managers.  They already do this.
- Don't use `pgrep` and `kill` under service managers.  They do this better.
- Don't use `start-stop-daemon` under service managers.  They do this better.

That entire mechanism with that shell script is wrongheaded to start with, and fixing its readiness protocol mismatch would be simply papering over some vast cracks.  You don't need any of that entire cobbled-together-poor-imitation-of-daemon-management script at all.  You *have* a service manager that can do that stuff *directly* and *safely*.  Use it.

```
# /etc/systemd/system/node@.service
[Unit]
Description=node service for %i.js
Documentation=https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207658/
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /home/www/html/%i.js
Restart=on-abort
SyslogIdentifier=node-%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Fix the path to `/usr/local/bin/node` as appropriate.
The usual commands then apply:

- `systemctl preset node@a.service node@b.service`
- `systemctl start node@a.service node@b.service`
- `systemctl status node@a.service node@b.service`

## Further reading

- Félix Saparelli (2013-11-26). [*How To Deploy Node.js Applications Using Systemd and Nginx*](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-node-js-applications-using-systemd-and-nginx).
- Ruben Vermeersch (2013-01-16). [*Deploying Node.js with systemd*](https://rocketeer.be/articles/deploying-node-js-with-systemd/).
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200365/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/625378/43344

Comment: I used your method and it worked for nodejs but its failing for to make turnserver. Can you download and install this then try to make it run you will see it fails http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v3.2.5.7/turnserver-3.2.5.7-CentOS7.1-x86_64.tar.gz

Comment: A comment is not the proper place to ask another question about a completely different software package; "it fails" is a useless problem description; and I am not going to download arbitrary softwares from unknown parts of the World Wide Web and run them, especially not to find an undisclosed bug of unspecified nature in an unknown location. When you have a question ask it properly with [ask], complete with a description of what _you_ did and what happens when _you_ run it per [the standard litany](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html).