# Why is systemd stopping service immediately after it is started?

Tags: systemd

I have a C++ based application which I'm running(executable) as a daemon with systemd.

Unit File:

```
[Unit]
Description=Console Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="USER=ubuntu" "Path=/home/ubuntu/console/bin" 
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/console/bin
ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec "exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon -S -c ${USER} -d ${Path} --pidfile=/var/run/console.pid --oknodo  --exec consoleExecutable " #2>/dev/null
ExecStop=/bin/sh -ec "exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon -K --quiet -c ${USER} -d ${Path} --pidfile=/var/run/console.pid  --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --oknodo --exec consoleExecutable" #2>/dev/null
Restart=on-failure
RemainAfterExit=no
TimeoutStopSec=10
SuccessExitStatus=0 1
TimeoutStartSec=360

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I issue start command the service is starting up, but then it immediately receives a shutdown signal and then exits.
Any clue, what is happening?

```
sudo systemctl status console.service
● console.service - Console Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/console.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Mon 2017-09-25 19:58:58 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 8706 ExecStop=/bin/sh -ec exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon -K --quiet -c ${USER} -d ${Path} --pidfile=/var/run/console.pid  --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --oknodo --exec consoleExecutable #2>/dev/null (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8701 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon -S -c ${USER} -d ${Path} --pidfile=/var/run/console.pid --oknodo  --exec consoleExecutable  #2>/dev/null (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8701 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 1.8M
      CPU: 53ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/console.service
           └─8705 consoleExecutable

Sep 25 19:58:58 mgmt1 systemd[1]: Started Console Service.

sudo systemctl status console.service
● console.service - Console Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/console.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2017-09-25 19:59:01 UTC; 947ms ago
  Process: 8706 ExecStop=/bin/sh -ec exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon -K --quiet -c ${USER} -d ${Path} --pidfile=/var/run/console.pid  --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --oknodo --exec consoleExecutable #2>/dev/null (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8701 ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon -S -c ${USER} -d ${Path} --pidfile=/var/run/console.pid --oknodo  --exec consoleExecutable  #2>/dev/null (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8701 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 25 19:58:58 mgmt1 systemd[1]: Started Console Service.
```

Comment: I see a bunch of `exited, status=0` messages. What evidence do you have that systemd is stopping your service?

Answer (score 15):

> ```
> Environment="USER=ubuntu" "Path=/home/ubuntu/console/bin" 
> WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/console/bin
> ExecStart=/bin/sh -ec "exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon -S -c ${USER} -d ${Path} --pidfile=/var/run/console.pid --oknodo  --exec consoleExecutable " #2>/dev/null
> ExecStop=/bin/sh -ec "exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon -K --quiet -c ${USER} -d ${Path} --pidfile=/var/run/console.pid  --retry=TERM/30/KILL/5 --oknodo --exec consoleExecutable" #2>/dev/null
> ```

This is almost worthy of the systemd House of Horror.  Were it not the case that there's a horror story already in there that does this.

Do not use `start-stop-daemon` in a service unit to do all of the things *that a service unit already does*.  With unnecessary PID files and the wrongheaded assumption that `ExecStart` accepts shell syntax comments, no less.

And do not do what the other answer says and try to bodge it with `Type=forking`.  That makes things worse, not better.

The nonsense with `start-stop-daemon` is why things are going wrong.  Because the process running `start-stop-daemon` does not *become* the service, but in fact exits pretty much imediately, systemd is thinking that your service is terminating.  In your first `systemctl status` output, you can see that systemd is in the middle of sending `SIGTERM` to clean up all left-over running processes after running the `ExecStop` action, which is what it does when it thinks that a service has terminated.

Just do things simply:

```
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/console/bin
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/console/bin/consoleExecutable
```

No `ExecStop` nor `Environment` is actually required.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*You really don't need to daemonize. Really.*](http://jdebp.info/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/daemonize.html).  The systemd House of Horror.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). [*If you have two services, define two services.*](http://jdebp.info/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/two-services.html).  The systemd House of Horror.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*](http://jdebp.info/FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html). Frequently Given Answers.
- [Systemd kills service immediately after start](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200280/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But still the issue persists.
deactivating (stop-sigterm) and then goes into inactive (dead) state.

Answer (score 6):

systemd thinks the pid of your daemon is 8701 which is the pid of `start-stop-daemon`. The pid of your daemon is 8705. You need to set `Type=forking` (under `[Service]`) in your unit file. The default is `Type=simple` which assumes the process does not fork.

However, why are you using this `/bin/sh -ec exec /sbin/start-stop-daemon` monstrosity? systemd can handle everything start-stop-daemon does.

Comment: I have used 'start-stop-daemon' in /etc/init.d/** script on ubuntu 14.04 which was working. So have been following the same commands to write systemd unit file(which didn't work).

Comment: I wasn't using start-stop-daemon, but was instead using python double-forking to start my process. Type=forking fixed my issue, thank you.