# systemd doesn't detect dead daemon process

Tags: systemd

I have a `aaa.service` file (controlling the JBoss), that besides other regular stuff contains

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/my/script start
ExecReload=/my/script restart
ExecStop=/my/script stop
PIDFile=...
```

`/my/script start` creates the PID-file and `service aaa status` shows it issuing a strange warning:

```
Supervising process xxx which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
```

Full output:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/aaa.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-01-22 20:55:16 CET; 34min ago
  Process: 32435 ExecStart=/my/script start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 32542
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/aaa.service

Jan 22 20:54:56 I011-830 su[32447]: (to aaa) root on none
Jan 22 20:54:56 I011-830 su[32447]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user aaa by (uid=0)
Jan 22 20:55:16 I011-830 aaa[32435]: Starting JBoss application server: Starting JBoss application server:
Jan 22 20:55:16 I011-830 systemd[1]: aaa.service: Supervising process 32542 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
```

Now my actual problem is, that if the process get killed other then by issuing `service aaa stop`, the systemd doesn't detect it. Even more it claims, that it's running and don't want to start it again:

```
# cat <pid-file>
No such file or directory
# service aaa status
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/aaa.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-01-22 20:55:16 CET; 40min ago
  Process: 32435 ExecStart=/konsens/app/aaa/init/aaastart (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 32542
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/aaa.service
 ...
# service aaa start
# <--- Instant return, no process started
```

How can I achieve following goals?

- systemd should be able to start and stop my service
- `service aaa status` should show the status of the process regardless if it was started by systemd or manually issuing `/my/service start`
- systemd should be able to start service after it was killed manually
- systemd should be able to stop service, that I have started manually

Comment: This is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437251/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434709/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394431/ , et al. again, with a minor variation upon not actually speaking the forking readiness protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I achieve following goals?
>   1 systemd should be able to start and stop my service

Most distributions have backwards compatibility so you can store your service in /etc/init.d/ if you don't want to make a native service.

> 2 service aaa status should show the status of the process regardless if it was started by systemd or manually issuing /my/service start

One way to do this is to add a check in your script to call `systemctl start aaa.service` if it was not called that way to begin with. a trap can be used for exit.

> 3 systemd should be able to start service after it was killed manually

solved by #2

> 4 systemd should be able to stop service, that I have started manually

solved by #2