# Why systemd stopping immediatly after spawning?

Tags: systemd, process, process-management, etc

I am facing issue while loading vpp.service in systemd.
I have written following service.

```
[Unit]
Description=Vector Packet Processing Process
After=syslog.target network.target auditd.service

[Service]
#ExecStartPre=-/bin/rm -f /dev/shm/db /dev/shm/global_vm /dev/shm/vpe-api
#ExecStartPre=-/sbin/modprobe uio_pci_generic
ExecStart=/usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp -c /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/startup_new.conf
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am getting following output :

```
vpp.service - Vector Packet Processing Process
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vpp.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) since Tue 2020-01-21 11:34:26 IST; 58s ago
  Process: 2019 ExecStart=/usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp -c /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/startup_new.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2019 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vpp.service
           └─2026 /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp -c /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/startup_new.conf

Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: pppoe_plugin.so (PPPoE)
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: router_plugin.so (router)
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: srv6ad_plugin.so (Dynamic SRv6 proxy)
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: srv6am_plugin.so (Masquerading SRv6 proxy)
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: srv6as_plugin.so (Static SRv6 proxy)
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: stn_plugin.so (VPP Steals the NIC for Container integration)
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: svs_plugin.so (Source VRF Select)
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: tlsopenssl_plugin.so (openssl based TLS Engine)
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:117: Plugin disabled (default): unittest_plugin.so
Jan 21 11:34:26 2-9.mavenir1.com vpp[2019]: load_one_plugin:189: Loaded plugin: vmxnet3_plugin.so (VMWare Vmxnet3 Device Plugin)
```

After some time I think I am getting crash like this :

```
[root@2-9 system]# systemctl status vpp
● vpp.service - Vector Packet Processing Process
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vpp.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #2  0x00007f41467cb5aa 0x7f41467cb5aa
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #3  0x00007f414611c5d0 0x7f414611c5d0
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #4  0x00007f4145e8b8d0 0x7f4145e8b8d0
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #5  0x00007f4145e90994 0x7f4145e90994
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #6  0x00007f4145eea984 0x7f4145eea984
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #7  0x00007f414520e5ac 0x7f414520e5ac
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #8  0x00007f41467cb9a7 0x7f41467cb9a7
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #9  0x0000000000406e1a 0x406e1a
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #10 0x00007f41450f4495 0x7f41450f4495
    Jan 21 11:32:20 2-9.mavenir1.com /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp[1712]: #11 0x00000000004079ff 0x4079ff
```

Can any one help me out ?

Comment: Systemd isn't stopping, this "vpp" is. What is it, where did you get it from and how did you install it?

Comment: vpp is opensource project. If I do manual commands then it is working. If I am creating  service it is giving problem like above.

Comment: /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/vpp -c /usr/IMS/current/bin/vpp/startup_new.conf                 This is the installation command for VPP

Answer (score 0):

systemd is not stopping anything.  **Your dæmon is exiting**, and systemd is cleaning up what you have told it are ancillary leftover processes.

In part, this is because you aren't running it in the way that the VPP doco states, which is [to have `nodaemon` in the configuration file](https://fd.io/docs/vpp/master/gettingstarted/users/configuring/startup.html#the-unix-section) and [to use `Type=simple`](https://fd.io/docs/vpp/master/gettingstarted/users/running/index.html#vpp-systemd-file-vpp-service).

And you've given people only a partial stack trace, with no symbols, to work from with the *earlier* (not "after some time"; read the timestamps) outright crash of your dæmon.  There's not a hope that the non-clairvoyants of the world can debug that.

> Can any one help me out ?

So, strictly speaking, the answer to this yes-no question is "No.".

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200365/5132